# How to redirect a page by a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on a page like this:

```
<div class="boxfather">
            <div class="box">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <button>See Dashboard</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now I want to add an action to this which can redirect the page to another page for example. So how can I do that ?

Note that it must be a button and not an input with type of submit!

Comment: Why do you need it to be a button? Just use an anchor, it is semantically wrong to use `<button>` instead of `<a>`.

Comment: <a href="URL"><button>See Dashboard</button></a>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a button as long as it's wrapper in a `<form>`. This will work even if Javascript is disabled.

```
<form method="get" action="http://example.com">
 <button type="submit">
 Click me
 </button>
</form>
```

I have a working example at https://jsfiddle.net/u5mxab1b/

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use `window.location.href` like below.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='LinkGoesHere'">See Dashboard</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href='b.php'">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change the value of `window.location.href` which will direct you to the url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc(){
    window.location.href = "https://someurl.com/";
}
</script>

<div class="boxfather">
            <div class="box">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <button onclick="myFunc()">See Dashboard</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this my friend.

```
<button> <a href="link to page"> See Dashboard </a> </button>
```

:))